# How to get OnClick Event on inflated view

Tags: android, events, inflate, android-inflate

I have inflated view from xml and added it to layout:

```
View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.lenta_parent_item,(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameContent), false);
header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View header) {
            ...some code
        }
    });
```

Main layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/frameContent">
<view ....

</FrameLayout>
```

When i run my app, I can see this view("header"), but when I click on it nothing happens. Event just not fired. What can i do to get click events for my view?

Answer (score 3):

am not clearly getting ur concept ,what u exactly want to click post ur full xml code.

```
View header ;
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
header=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lenta_parent_item,null, false);
```

i think u r trying to click the customExapandablelistview right,then try like this.

```
PinnedHeaderExpListView listviewpinned=(PinnedHeaderExpListView )header.findViewbyId(R.id.list);
    listviewpinned.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View header) {
            ...some code
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want click on view,that i added on the layout. I can see it, but can't click

Comment: ok what view u want to click it.take the Reference of that view.

Comment: checkout my edited code above and take the reference like what i am doing in the code for the View .for which u want to click.

Comment: what is the difference?! header is abstract view and i want to receive OnClick events for it, but it doesnt happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613552/pinned-groups-in-expandablelistview/10753147

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to set `android:clickable="false"`for all the views contained in your FrameLayout, and set `android:clickable="true"` for the FrameLayout itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lenta_parent_item, null);
 header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...some code
    }
});
```

Comment: how view will be able to get event, if it doesn't have a parent?!