# Disable ExpandableListView group header to move while scrolling

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using ExpandableListView in my app, when I expand group and scroll to child list; group header also moved up with scroll. Any one please help me to disable **group header** from moving up only child list should move up.

Please help me implementing this feature.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: did u get this working ? Pls post the solution.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248531/how-to-get-sticky-pinned-headers-in-an-expandablelistview) is a good example how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think You can't do this with ExpandableListView.

There are many other way available to make this

You should check,

**StickyListHeaders** : https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

**HeaderListView**    : https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView, http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/

It might help you..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ajay's answer, you can see Cabezas' trick of using ExpandableListView in a ScrollView [here](https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/)

Alternatively, you can create a custom NonScrollExpandableListView class like so:

```
public class NonScrollExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {
public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public NonScrollExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
    params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

}

For the full implementation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605908/8771403