# Android - Thumb of fastscroll in expandablelistview doesnt scroll list correctly

Tags: android, expandablelistview, fastscroll

i am using an expandablelistview to show a list of groups containing different counts of children. sometimes the list is very long, so i wanted to enable fastscroll. i did this and everything is working fine when i scroll the list with the finger in the usual way.

but when i grab the thumb and drag it to the bottom, the list is scrolled to the last position when i have moved the thumb about 1/3 of the height from the top. what can i do to have the thumb position the list according to the full height of the scrollbar?

Comment: Are there any updates from Google about addressing this fastscroll bug?

Comment: Same problem did anyone find a good solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Last answer went missing.

This is a known bug in Android FastScroller.

See my code attached to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24635

it contains a work-around that works for some specific cases.

Comment: After a long time i updated my project and used the FastScroller you mentioned. Unfortunately it seems that there are listsizes where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277901/1217871). It uses a `OnScrollListener` to act differently if the user scrolls via touch or via thumb.

Comment: @ mitch000001, I've tried your code in my ExpandableListView app, but it gave me a NullPointerException force close error whenever I expanded any group. Do I need the SectionIndexer.java in order to make it to work? Can you please help me on this?  Thank you