# How to get FastScroll to work with ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, fastscroll

I am trying to enable the Fast Scroll in ExpandableListView, and I've tried the workaround solution from this link: [android fastScroll only covers part of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461804/android-fastscroll-only-covers-part-of-the-list)

The problem is that it gives me the NullPointerException error whenever I expand enough groups to trigger the fast scroll bar.
I've tried the following code:

```
MainActivity:
expandblelist = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.mexpandablelistview);
Adapter = new Adapter(this, expandblelist, category_array);
expandblelist.setAdapter(Adapter);
expandblelist.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

Adapter:
public class Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
                                implements SectionIndexer, AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private List<Category> mGroupCollection;
    private int[] groupStatus;
        private boolean manualScroll;
        private String[] groups;

    public Adapter(Context context, ExpandableListView pExpandableListView, List<Category> pGroupCollection) {
        mContext = context;
        mGroupCollection = pGroupCollection;
        mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
        groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];
        setListEvent(); 
        this.mExpandableListView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        this.manualScroll = scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, 
                         int firstVisibleItem, 
                         int visibleItemCount, 
                         int totalItemCount) {}

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        if (manualScroll) {
            return section;
        } else {            
            return mExpandableListView.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(section));
        }
    }

    // Gets called when scrolling the list manually
    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(mExpandableListView.getExpandableListPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSections() {
    return groups;
    }

LogCat:
NullPointerException
FastScroller.getThumbPositionForListPosition(FastScroller.java:680)
FastScroller.onScroll(FastScroller.java:487)
at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1337)
```

Can someone please guide me on this?
I very appreciate for your time and help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: which SDK level are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest Eclipse/ADT since September 2014.  Target Android 4.3

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `getSections` to return your String array "groups", but the array does not appear to be initialized anywhere (unless it is done in code that you have not posted). `mSections` in FastScroller is initialized to the result of a getSections call, so you get a NullPointerException when FastScroller tries to access that field; the line giving you the NPE is

```
final int sectionCount = mSections.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't have groups array initialized anywhere in any other classes.  I was just following the solution from the link in my question post.  Obviously, something is missing, and I've tried to ask the person in that link a question, but no one has not yet replied.  I don't quite understand how this workaround solution works..  Is there anyway can provide some example code?  I don't have this code in my app: final int sectionCount = mSections.length;     Thanks a lot

Comment: That code is from Android's FastScroller class -- that's where the exception is coming from. I'm not sure what "groups" should be initialized to based on your code, but try at least instantiating it in your constructor (i.e. `groups = new String[0];`) and it should at least eliminate that NPE.